# How they works: DB-Connect and SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql, include, sql-injection, dbconnection

My question is regarding the application of a DB connection and SQL injection. I am using the codes provided below to successfully connect to my database. I would like to ask:

1. How the foreach stops SQL injection?
2. If there is a better more efficient way to make the connection more secure?
3. Will the connection still work and provide me with valid data from the database, if dbconnect.php were to be included in another file (for example; global.php), which in return was included in the main file where the actual use of database is?

**example_file.php:**

```
<?php 
//MySQL Database Connect
include './includes/dbconnect.php'; 


//This stops SQL Injection in POST vars
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}
//This stops SQL Injection in GET vars
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
  $_GET[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}
?>
```

**dbconnect.php:**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");

if (!$con){ die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db("databasename", $con);

?>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. > How the foreach stops SQL injection?

   This is really *really* important, so I'm going to say it very loudly in the hope that people might understand…

   ## IT DOESN'T!

   "*Why not?*", I hear you ask.  Well, my young padawan, that is because:

   1. ### It only escapes *strings*

      Let's imagine a website through which users can view their medical records.  To enable the user to filter his records for those related to a particular illness, one permits the illness to be specified by its `id` as a query parameter:

      http://www.example.com/health/fetchmyrecords.php?illness=123

      The developer first applies the `foreach` loop in your question and then assumes "*phew, I'm safe from SQL injection—nothing more to worry about!*", so then does:

      ```php
      $res = mysql_query("
        SELECT *
        FROM   health_records
        WHERE  user    = $_SESSION[uid]
           AND illness = $_GET[illness]
      ");
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) print_r($row);
      ```

      Can you see the problem?  Have a think about it.

      > #### The problem
      >
      > Suppose someone requests the following URI:
      >
      > http://www.example.com/health/fetchmyrecords.php?illness=123+OR+1
      >
      > MySQL will then receive the following query:
      >
      > ```sql
      > SELECT *
      > FROM   health_records
      > WHERE  user    = 987
      >    AND illness = 123 OR 1
      > ```
      >
      > **SQL successfully injected!**  In this particular example the injection is *fatal*, since MySQL will parse that `WHERE` clause as:
      >
      > ```sql
      > WHERE (user = 987 AND illness = 123) OR 1
      > ```
      >
      > …so it will actually return *every health record of every user in the database*!
      >
      > <sup>Good luck affording the legal fees that will come out of that.  It's a reasonable guess that your business will collapse, your personal finances will be ruined, your house will be repossessed, your wife will leave you, your kids won't speak to you and your cat will run away!</sup>

      The explanation (for the injection, not your cat's disappearance) is that one can only escape *strings* with `mysql_real_escape_string()` (the clue is in the name).  It can't be used to escape any other SQL token: not [number literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/number-literals.html); not [identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifiers.html); and certainly not SQL keywords or special characters.  Those tokens must be secured in some other way.

      Thus arbitrarily escaping *every* received variable irrespective of its meaning is almost certainly incorrect.  Furthermore, the results are only useful in SQL: should you want to use those variables for anything else, the data will be munged—so you really shouldn't store the results back in the `$_GET` and `$_POST` arrays anyway.
   2. ### It only *escapes* strings

      For the variables that are in fact strings, merely applying `mysql_real_escape_string()` won't necessarily stop SQL injection.  You must also correctly *quote* the [String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html):

      > A string is a sequence of bytes or characters, enclosed within either single quote (“`'`”) or double quote (“`"`”) characters.

      However, if the MySQL server is in the [`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) SQL mode, then `mysql_real_escape_string()` does not safely escape strings for use within double quotes.  So, to be safe, you must either:

      - use single-quoted literals; or
      - explicitly set some other SQL mode.

      Furthermore, before calling `mysql_real_escape_string()` you *must* have first told your MySQL client library with which character encoding the server will interpret such strings—usually by calling [`mysql_set_charset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) (however, there are some encoding-related injections that even this won't defeat if you're using a really old version of the client library).

   See [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187/623041) for more detail.

   ## Summing up

   - **use an up to date client library**
   - **call `mysql_set_charset()`**
   - **either disable `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`, or else use single-quoted literals**
   - **use `mysql_real_escape_string()` only on string literals**
   - **don't use the result for anything other than producing SQL**
   - **make other tokens safe in some other way**
2. > If there is a better more efficient way to make the connection more secure?

   Yes, there most certainly is—and has been for some years.  In fact, so much so that `mysql_real_escape_string()` really ought to be considered an anti-pattern.  It should never be used.

   Sadly, tutorial after tutorial continue to teach this ridiculously outdated and dangerous method of constructing SQL.  Many of them have been around since before time itself, so it might be excusable that they were *originally* written badly (but by now they really ought to be updated, deleted or ignored); however for every new course or tutorial that recommends use of `mysql_real_escape_string()`, God kills a kitten. **Won't somebody think of the kittens?!**

   The "better way" is really two-fold:

   1. Stop using those PHP functions that are prefixed with `mysql_`.  They were originally introduced in PHP v2.0 for MySQL v3.23, and no new features have been added since 2006.  The manual has contained warnings against their use in new code since June 2011 and they have been officially deprecated in PHP v5.5.

      PHP ships with two perfectly good, modern alternatives: [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)—see [MySQL: Choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for help deciding which to use.
   2. Using one of those alternative APIs, you can *parameterise* your SQL statements so that literal values are transmitted to the server independently of the statement itself: thus the server will not even *attempt* to parse those literal values for SQL, irrespective of the values they contain.  Injection simply *cannot* happen from a literal value (note that you will still need to protect other tokens, but that is a far less common requirement and beyond the scope of this answer).

   See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/623041)
3. > Will the connection still work and provide me with valid data from the database, if dbconnect.php were to be included in another file (for example; global.php), which in return was included in the main file where the actual use of database is?

   Yes.  It is quite common in large projects for included files to include further files.

Comment: +1 from me - excellent piece! - but doesn't the canonical answer you referenced cover all this? I'd be minded to close the question as essentially a dup, but I'd rather hear your view first.

Comment: This answer rather missing the point. The "foreach" problem is a magic quotes problem, already explained elsewhere. No need to add edge cases - they will only confuse a reader making him think he's reading something important. Also, there is noting wrong with mysql_real_escape_string(), and it can be used all right. First variant was dramatically better and way more readable and helpful.

Comment: @halfer: I started approaching it from two slightly different perspectives, but they might have got lost in the detail.  First, why escaping *every* variable is wrong; second, why overwriting the values in `$_POST` and `$_GET` is wrong.  The canonical "use parameterised statements" answer really only addresses the OP's second question, and that is why I've given a relatively short answer to that part.

Comment: @eggyal, alright, that's good enough for me. Thanks! (And to be fair, the other question doesn't have enough cats in it).

Comment: @YourCommonSense: How does the revision miss either of those points?  It addresses the "foreach" issue under the box headed "**The problem**" and provides the circumstances in which mysql_real_escape_string() is safe to use under the heading "**Summing up**".

Comment: @YourCommon, aw we'd miss your positive contributions if you weren't here to make 'em!

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Yep, my sole *raison d'être* is to amuse and entertain.  I have absolutely no desire to share knowledge or educate! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That cleared up a a lot of things and the read was very interesting. Seems like I have some research and updates to do. Thanks again! :D